# Fibonacci Sequence ,binary search

Tags: c++, search, binary, numbers, fibonacci

I am trying to solve the following problem:

F is an infinite sequence of integers that satisfies to Fibonacci condition F(i + 2) = F(i + 1) + F(i) for any integer i. Write a program, which calculates the value of F(n) for the given values of F(i) and F(j).

Input:
The input contains five integers in the following order: i, F(i), j, F(j), n.
−1000 ≤ i, j, n ≤ 1000, i ≠ j,
−2·10^9 ≤ F(k) ≤ 2·10^9 (k = min(i, j, n), …, max(i, j, n)).

Output:
The output consists of a single integer, which is the value of F(n).

I am trying to solve this problem by finding F(min(i,j)+1) then using that two neighbors to find F(n). I was told that this can be done by implementing binary search on the interval (-2*10^9,2*10^9) ,but I don't understand how to use binary search here.Could give me a hint or explain the algorithm in a short manner.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think of is like that: lets say i < j and F(i) < F(j) so we want to find F(i+1).
We know that F(i) < F(i+1) < F(j) so we can do binary search between [F(i),F(j)] - each time we guess F(i+1) and checks if it fits (no easy way around it I think) until you get the correct value.

Complexity - each iteration can take 2000 steps (worst case), and at worst it's going to take be log(4*10^9) iterations which is about 32 so it seems reasonable.

Comment: How do you decide in what interval to continue your search after dividing?

Comment: You just try it. You calculate all the value from the guessed F(i+1) to F(n), if it's too small then you need to select the higher interval, if it's too big then the lower one.